# Sqlite or Array List

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I am unsure of what would be the best method to save data in my app. Its its Map app and for each location I would want to save certain characteristics for example like shown here:
  [image]

- I wouldn't need to be able to edit the data in the app It could just
  be readable.
- I would want the be able to search if each Id had certain
  attributes then only display those on a map.
- I would also want to be able to access the data
  for display on a map
- There would be up to around 400 Id's.
- The Data would ideally be stored in different types (string, integer, decimal).

Would it be best to save this data in a database like SQLite or a massive array list, or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: better use Sqlite since u have N number of rows, it is easy to store as well as to access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLite](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) is a opensource SQL database that stores data to a text file on a device. Android comes in with built in SQLite database implementation.

1. > If you have data related with each other, file will not allow you to
   >       relate them. At that time SQLite will help you.
2. > If you wan to query your data, store the data in structured manner
   >       you will prefer SQLite Than ArrayList
3. > SQLite has higher performance

Please read this article [Why should we use SQLite in Android development?](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-we-use-SQLite-in-Android-development)

**My Advise**

Use **`Sqlite`** .